# JTree setSelectionPaths takes too long to expand

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am using `JTree` and I am selecting all the nodes in the tree (Ctrl-A). My tree contains 14000 parents and each parent has a child, so in total the tree contains 28000 nodes.  Following is the code snippet:

```
@Override public final void setSelectionPaths(TreePath[] aPaths)
  {
    if (aPaths != null)
   {

   for (TreePath path : aPaths)
   {
       TreePath parentPath = path.getParentPath();
       if (parentPath != null)
        {
          expandPath(path.getParentPath());
        }
      }
    }
    super.setSelectionPaths(aPaths);
  }
```

It takes 20 minutes to expand the tree. Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: Is there any logical way to partition your tree into subtrees?

Comment: +1 for "It takes 20 minutes to expand the tree." Have you actually waited that long?

Answer (score -1):

I found that after recording the selected paths, if you reset the selection before expanding, it's incredibly faster.

```
final TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
//Modifying the selection makes it run a whole lot faster
tree.setSelectionPath(paths[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
    tree.expandPath(paths[i]);
}
```

I assume this is because it doesn't have to do so much magic with the selection any more.

Through the fear of being beaten up and left for dead, I'll provide this suggestion.  If you want to leave the GUI unlocked during this process, you could throw it onto a new Thread (not on the EDT).  Of course you have to be really careful that nothing tries to interact at all with the Tree - Swing isn't thread safe, so anything other than looking at it will cause all sorts of funky problems.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class JTreeExpanding extends Box{

    //Just to make sure no user interactions happen during expansion
    JPanel glassPane = new JPanel(){
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,80));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(18f).deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
            g.drawString("Processing...", getWidth()-100, getHeight()-10);
        }
    };

    public JTreeExpanding(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        glassPane.setOpaque(false);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        for(int i = 0; i < 14000; i++){
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root" + i);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child" + i));
            root.add(node);
        }   

        final JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        add(pane);

        JButton button = new JButton("Expand");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Taking the expand off the EDT frees up GUI 
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
                        //Modifying the selection makes it run a whole lot faster
                        tree.setSelectionPath(paths[0]);
                        for(int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
                            tree.expandPath(paths[i]);
                        }
                        glassPane.setVisible(false);
                    }});

                getRootPane().setGlassPane(glassPane);
                glassPane.setVisible(true);
                t.start();
            }});
        add(button);

        //Allow Scrolling in scroll pane while Tree is expanding
        glassPane.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                for(MouseWheelListener mwl : pane.getMouseWheelListeners()){
                    mwl.mouseWheelMoved(e);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new JTreeExpanding());
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: you knew you would get a -1 for the off-EDT stuff, didn't you :-) Good observation, that clearing the selection before expanding (and not forgetting to re-select when done) makes a huge difference

Comment: @kleopatra - I was hoping a good idea could offset a touchy idea and you just wouldn't vote.  That and if my example locked the UI so it was read only, my transgressions would be forgivable.  Doing experimentation, it seems to work fine (perhaps `expandPath` or it's delegates are synchronized). I'd rather push the edge of what's okay and get boo-ed, than do only what's acceptable.

Comment: there is no way to test misbehaviour due to EDT violations plus some future jdk might decide to somehow enforce it (as the current did with validateTree) - simply don't, the probability for blowing is just to high. On the other hand, it is a tricky problem, and unsolved maybe even unsolveable in the general case. The best-bet is to do it _on_ the EDT in a way the user doesn't notice: after all, s/he is only seeing a small part of the total. Not entirely trivial, though. See f.i. http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1467 and referenced discussions)

Comment: forgot: as a side-effect of age all datastructures underlying the default models are synchronized - which might (or not, don't know the relative importance) mitigate any bad effects. Being an accidental implementation detail, it's nothing to rely on :-)

Comment: @kleopatra - I added another answer to help satisfy our desire to keep the EDT clean.  I just had a hard time posting an answer that locks the user's screen for 11+ seconds... So I added my wrong (EDT) to the wrong of JTree's lack of collection update methods in hopes of something a little more right.  Please forgive me.

Answer (score -1):

To satisfy myself and @kleopatra, I've come up with a better implementation (which on my machine saves ~8 seconds over the previous answer).  Basically it adds another method to `JTree` for expanding selected paths.

This method cuts out some of the overhead of not necessary with expanding selected nodes, and fires UI updates after all the internal states have been set.  The method is based on the native implementation of `JTable.setExpandedState`.  I've also left code in so you can see the performance differences on your machine.

Best of all - it's not messing with the EDT anymore (because at 3.5 seconds for 14k nodes... why would you).

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class JTreeExpanding extends Box{

    public JTreeExpanding(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);

        //Populating a sample tree
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        for(int i = 0; i < 14000; i++){
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root" + i);
            node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Child" + i));
            root.add(node);
        }   

        //Create a custom tree
        final CustomTree tree = new CustomTree(root);
        //final JTree tree = new JTree(root);
        tree.setRootVisible(false);
        final JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        add(pane);

        //Create a button to expand the selected nodes
        JButton button = new JButton("Expand");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //New way using Custom JTree
                tree.expandSelectedPaths();

                //Old way using classic JTree
                /*TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
                tree.setSelectionPath(paths[0]);
                for(TreePath path : paths)
                    tree.expandPath(path);*/
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
            }});
        add(button);

    }

    public static class CustomTree extends JTree{

        HashMap<TreePath, Boolean> expandedState = new HashMap<TreePath, Boolean>();
        Stack<TreePath> customExpandedStack = new Stack<TreePath>();

        public CustomTree(DefaultMutableTreeNode root) {
            super(root);
        }

        public void expandSelectedPaths(){

            final TreePath[] paths = getSelectionPaths();
            setSelectionPath(paths[0]);

            for(TreePath path: paths){
                TreePath parentPath = path.getParentPath();

                while(parentPath != null) {
                    if(isExpanded(parentPath)) {
                        parentPath = null;
                    }
                    else {
                        customExpandedStack.push(parentPath);
                        parentPath = parentPath.getParentPath();
                    }
                }

                for(int counter = customExpandedStack.size() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
                    parentPath = customExpandedStack.pop();
                    if(!isExpanded(parentPath)) {
                        expandedState.put(parentPath, Boolean.TRUE);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (accessibleContext != null) {
                ((AccessibleJTree)accessibleContext).
                fireVisibleDataPropertyChange();
            }

            for(TreePath path : paths){
                fireTreeExpanded(path);
                try {
                    fireTreeWillExpand(path);
                } catch (ExpandVetoException eve) {
                    // Expand vetoed!
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new JTreeExpanding());
        frame.validate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry, but this is even worse (if anything could be worse than violating the EDT rule ;-) It's completely by-passing the internal bookkeeping of expansion state, thus given incorrect results for all methods querying/relying on that state (f.i. isExpanded(..) returning false even though the node _is_ expanded)